# How do I reply using a file in Fiddler Everywhere Free?

Tags: debugging, web, fiddler-everywhere

I am trying to replace a production js file on a site with a local copy of it so I can set my own event listeners and control the layout of the page as needed. A lot of old stackoverflow answers suggest using fiddler to do that, but apparently the UI has changed since then. I have added the file I want changed to the autoresponder list but it does not have an option to return a file. The closest I've gotten is return a manual response which I have to copy and paste a 50k line javascript file every time. Can I get a more detailed explanation of how to do this in the new UI or was this removed from the free version of Fiddler Everywhere?

Comment: Fiddler Everywhere is a totally new product that only shares the name "Fiddler". You can still use the old (and IMHO better) .Net based Fiddler tool (now called "Fiddler Classic").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Auto Responder** and create a rule that uses an external file. The file could contain the whole mocked response including the references (or the content) of the JS script.

To achieve the above use the last action from the Action drop-down which is named ***Choose saved response file ...*** (see more about the actions [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65366631/4936697)).