# Fiddler everyone doesn't capture traffic

Tags: macos, fiddler-everywhere

I try to work with Fidler Everywhere on Mac.
Early all worked well, but in the one moment (I nothing change - just closed the app and opened after a month ago). Now Fiddler doesn't capture any traffic and I do not know what I can do with this.

[image]

Comment: Try to inspect the [log files](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/accessing-fiddler-logs) and add anything suspicious to the question. Also - the product is currently in active development so the team will probably be pretty responsive to specific reports in the [forums](https://community.getfiddler.com/support/discussions).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Fiddler doesn't override the System HTTP Proxy property. Let go to Network -> Wifi -> Advanced -> Proxies Tab and see whether or not the HTTP/HTTPS Proxy is checked and points to Fiddler's Port (It might be not 9090).

[image: System Proxies]

Alternatively, you can check out [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io), which is a native and modern macOS app. You can do everything Fiddler does with Proxyman.

Disclaimer: I create this app and it would be easier for you to use and resolve your problem.